# Cleveref format for enumerate

Tags: enumerate, cleveref

I've modified my enumerate environment using the following sentences:

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\textbf{\arabic{enumi}.}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\textbf{(\alph{enumii})}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\textbf{(\roman{enumiii})}}
```

However, if I write something as

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \label{refme}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

and then refer it using `according to \cref{refme}`, I'm getting "according to 1a" instead of "according to 1.(a)".

Is it possible to do something so that it respects my modified format?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of manipulating the low-level macros `\labelenumi`, `\labelenumii`, and `\labelenumiii` directly, I suggest you (a) load the `enumitem` package, (b) create a custom enumerated list called `myenum` and define the `label` and `ref` properties of levels 1 thru 3 of such list items.

[image]

Speaking for myself, I can't help but remark that the citation call-outs look both ugly and distracting. At the very least, do consider not using a **bold typeface** for the cross-references.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,cleveref}

\newlist{myenum}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[myenum,1]{label=\textbf{\arabic*.},
                   ref  =\textbf{\arabic*.}}
\setlist[myenum,2]{label=\textbf{(\alph*)},
                   ref  =\themyenumi\textbf{(\alph*)}}
\setlist[myenum,3]{label=\bfseries(\roman*),
                   ref  =\themyenumii\textbf{.(\roman*)}}

\crefname{myenumi}{item}{items}
\crefname{myenumii}{item}{items}
\crefname{myenumiii}{item}{items}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenum}
\item \label{refone}
  \begin{myenum}
    \item \label{reftwo} bla bla
    \begin{myenum}
      \item \label{refthree} bleep bleep
    \end{myenum}
  \end{myenum}
\item \label{reffour}
  \begin{myenum}
    \item xxx
    \item \label{reffive} bli bli
    \begin{myenum}
      \item yyy
      \item \label{refsix} bloop bloop
    \end{myenum}
  \end{myenum}
\end{myenum}

\noindent
Cross-references to \cref{refone,reffour}, \cref{reftwo,reffive}, and \cref{refthree,refsix}.  
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you insist on using the low-level macros `\labelenumi`, `\labelenumii`, and `\labelenumiii`, I think you should use the following code in the preamble. Note that this code also modifies `\theenumi`, `\theenumii`, and `\theenumiiii` as well as the "prefix macros" `\p@enumi` and `\p@enumiii`. (Observe that this code will *not* use bold-face while typesetting the cross-referencing call-outs. This is because I think it's really ugly to create bold-faced cross-referencing call-outs.)

```
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{(\alph{enumii})}
\renewcommand{\theenumiii}{(\roman{enumiii})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\textbf{\theenumi.}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\textbf{\theenumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\textbf{\theenumiii}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@enumii{\theenumi}
\renewcommand\p@enumiii{\theenumi\theenumii}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Worked great except for one thing: when referring, the `enumi' part applied corresponds to the actual value of the counter and not the one I'm referring to.

Comment: @mflopeza - Please see my revised answer.

Comment: Went with the new environment and worked like a charm! Also followed your advice of omitting the **boldface** in the cross-reference. Thanks!