# Numberwithin with enumitem

Tags: cross-referencing, enumitem, cleveref

From this [topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410585/cleveref-format-for-enumerate), I've implemented Mico's answer. Now, I want to reference figures this enumeration too. For instance,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,cleveref}

\newlist{myenum}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[myenum,1]{label=\textbf{\arabic*.},
                   ref  =\textbf{\arabic*.}}
\setlist[myenum,2]{label=\textbf{(\alph*)},
                   ref  =\themyenumi\textbf{(\alph*)}}
\setlist[myenum,3]{label=\bfseries(\roman*),
                   ref  =\themyenumii\textbf{.(\roman*)}}

\crefname{myenumi}{item}{items}
\crefname{myenumii}{item}{items}
\crefname{myenumiii}{item}{items}

\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}
\numberwithin{figure}{myenumi}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenum}
\item 
   \begin{figure}
      \caption{The Universe.\label{fig:universe}}
      \includegraphics{universe}
   \end{figure}
\end{myenum}

As shown in \cref{fig:universe}.

\end{document}
```

However, these lines got me this error: "Missing \endcsname inserted. \caption". Any ideas about how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead put your fragments into a complete compilable document that people can play with.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry about that.

Comment: a `figure` is a float and can't be nested within anything else.  next, a label on a figure should be associated with a caption.  the first problem can be solved by just inserting the graphic with `\incudegraphics` (omitting the `figure`).  some other type of anchor will be needed for the `\label`.  unfortunately, i'm not in a position to be able to test anything, but this might give a pointer to another helper.

Comment: I edited it to add the label to a caption.

Comment: That's not quite @barbarabeeton's  point: you can't use the `figure` environment inside your enumeration.

Comment: On the assumption that you don't want *all* figures to be within your `myenum` environment, it doesn't really make sense to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @barbarabeeton has already pointed out in a comment, one can't use a LaTeX "float" object (such as a `figure` environment) inside an enumeration. To work around this, I suggest you load the `caption` package and use `\captionof{figure}{...}` directives to generate the captions. I also suggest you use `minipage` environments to encase the graphs and their associated `\captionof` directives. That way, you can assure that the captions will be centered above the respective graphs.

Separately, I would also like to suggest that cross-references **not be rendered in bold-face**.

[image]

A final comment, to echo the comment by @AlanMunn: Unless *all* graphs are associated with level-1 enumerated items, your proposed setup doesn't make a lot of (typographic) sense. In fact, it should probably be avoided.

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,enumitem}

\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % for "\captionof" macro
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newlist{myenum}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[myenum,1]{label=\textbf{\arabic*.},
                   ref  =\arabic*}
\setlist[myenum,2]{label=\textbf{(\alph*)},
                   ref  =\themyenumi.(\alph*)}
\setlist[myenum,3]{label=\bfseries(\roman*),
                   ref  =\themyenumii.(\roman*)}
\crefname{myenumi}{item}{items}
\crefname{myenumii}{item}{items}
\crefname{myenumiii}{item}{items}

\numberwithin{figure}{myenumi}
\begin{document}

\begin{myenum}
\item  
   \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth} % choose width suitably
      \captionof{figure}{The Universe.}
      \label{fig:universe}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{universe}
   \end{minipage}
\end{myenum}

As shown in \cref{fig:universe}, \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, all my graphs are associated with level-1 enumerated items, so this worked great. Thanks.