# Numberwithin with enumitem 2

Tags: equations, hyperref, cross-referencing, enumitem, cleveref

Following [topic1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410585/cleveref-format-for-enumerate) and [topic2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411336/numberwithin-with-enumitem), I've implemented Mico's answers. Now, I want to reference equations under this enumeration too. For instance,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem,cleveref}

\newlist{myenum}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[myenum,1]{label=\textbf{\arabic*.},
                   ref  =\arabic*}
\setlist[myenum,2]{label=\textbf{(\alph*)},
                   ref  =\themyenumi.(\alph*)}
\setlist[myenum,3]{label=\bfseries(\roman*),
                   ref  =\themyenumii.(\roman*)}

\numberwithin{equation}{myenumi}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenum}
\item 
   \begin{equation}\label{eq:euler}
      e^{i\pi}+1 = 0
   \end{equation}
\end{myenum}

As shown in \cref{eq:euler}.

\end{document}
```

However, these lines got me this error: "Missing \endcsname inserted. \begin{equation}". Any ideas about why is this happening and/or how to solve this? Thanks.

**Edit:** I've discovered that this occurs when including the `\usepackage{hyperref}` line.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't actually produce the error you say you're getting. Please revise your posting as needed.

Comment: Off-topic: For the first-level myenum enumeration, I think the cross-referencing option should be "`ref =\arabic*`", *not* "`ref  =\arabic*.`".

Comment: Thanks! You were right at both times. I've edited the post accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you've encountered an incompatibility between the `enumitem` and `hyperref` packages. I'm afraid I'm not in a position to offer a full fix. All I can suggest is that you not use the `enumitem` package and, instead, modify the low-level macros `\theenumi`, `\labelenumi`, `\theenumii`, `\labelenumii`, `\p@enumii`, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{(\alph{enumii})}
\renewcommand{\theenumiii}{(\roman{enumiii})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\textbf{\theenumi.}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\textbf{\theenumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\textbf{\theenumiii}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@enumii{\theenumi} % "prefixes" for use in cross-references
\renewcommand\p@enumiii{\theenumi\theenumii}
\makeatother

\numberwithin{equation}{enumi}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 
   \begin{equation}\label{eq:euler}
      e^{i\pi}+1 = 0
   \end{equation}
\end{enumerate}

As shown in \cref{eq:euler}, \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed but didn't know how to add the prefixes. Thank you so much!